# Какую среду разработки стоит взять начинающему в C#?

Tags: visual-studio, c#

Среда нужна для ознакомительных целей: посмотреть на язык и сопутствующие библиотеки.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Стоит загрузить и установить Visual C# 2010 Express. Из плюсов:

- эта IDE доступна для свободного скачивания с сайта Microsoft;
- есть локализанная версия на русском языке.

Comment: Не сказал бы, что локализация — это плюс :).

Answer (score 8):

Лучше установи Visual Studio 2010 C# + ReSharper 2010.
Сама студия как IDE будет на родном языке и помогать с синтаксисом и командами Решарпер.

Answer (score 4):

Если только для ознакомления с языком и библиотеками - возьми любую доступную для тебя visual studio начиная с 2008.

Answer (score 0):

Почему Вы не рассматриваете последние версии VS ?
Мне кажется стоит попробовать именно их.
А так я использую [вот эту версию.](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs.aspx)
Если вопрос стоит в *деньгах* и *бесплатности*, то советую [эту версию.](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs.aspx)
А вообще, ссылки на **торрент** тут можно выкидывать ? (сарказм).

Comment: последние версии VS не рассматривают потому, что сам вопрос и все ответы - из 2011 года. Тогда 2010-я студия была совсем новьем!

Answer (score -4):

Visual Studio 2008
2010 Вижла глючная. Мне не понравилась. 2008 - лучшее из Вижлов, выпущенная Мягкософтом:)